# How to plot a function, with color mapped to one of its parameter?

Tags: plotting

```
pF[x_,p_] = x+p;
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pF[x,p],{p,0,5}]],{x,0,10}]
```

I want to map `p` value to color each curve differently from the color set : `ColorData["Rainbow"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code  keeps the style near the code of the functions `pF[...]` :

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Style[pF[x, p], ColorData["Rainbow"][p/5]], {p, 0, 5}]], {x, 
  0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
pF[x_, p_] = x + p;
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pF[x, p], {p, 0, 5}]], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.2])
 , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Syed...Can you please explain : `& /@ Range[0, 1, 0.2]` part. I want to map p from 0 to 5.

Comment: Syed's code is equivalent to `Plot[
 Evaluate[Table[pF[x, p], {p, 0, 5}]], {x, 0, 10}
 , PlotStyle -> Table[ColorData["Rainbow"][p/5], {p, 0, 5}]
 , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: The `Range` command creates divisions from 0 to 1 at intervals of 0.2. You can experiment with the answer and put the cursor on what you need help with and press F1 to consult documentation.